# mysql: how to add? "column1" + "column2" where id_parent is equal

Tags: mysql, addition

i have a table "photos" with a column "relevance" and another one named "trend".
i want to (add) "relevance"+"trend" where id_parent equal
I will set trend=0 after. What i  need is to update the column "relevance" first.

```
id_parent   relevance   trend
1            1000        30
2            200        10
3            4000        120
4            100        110
```

So far:

```
update photos set relevance=relevance+trend where...;
```

Comment: update your question and based on you sample add  a coherent expected  result

Comment: the query provided above is working fine, [what are you trying to ask exactly](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below - with a `Update Join`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e95894bd66c72b73e1e8d0bcb1d4e795)**

```
UPDATE photos p
        INNER JOIN
    photos p1 ON p.id_parent= p1.id_parent
SET 
    p.relevance=p.relevance+p.trend, p.trend=0
```

Comment: update+join is nice. Learned something new again, thank you so much.